# get several fields and iterate over array

Tags: json, jq

How can I combine this with jq? Both work independently but I can't make them work together:

`jq '.objects[].addresses[] | .id, .ipValue.ipStr, .hostName'`

`jq '.objects[] | .id, .name'`

This does not work:

`jq '.objects[] | .id, .name, .addresses[] | .id, .ipValue.ipStr, .hostName'`

In other words, print the `.id.`, `.name`, and iterate over addresses array and print `.id`, `.ipValue.ipStr` and `.hostName`??

Comment: Better add the input file or a sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, pipe operator has a higher precedence than comma operator.

```
.objects[] | .id, .name, (.adresses[] | .id, .ipValue.ipStr, .hostName)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
jq -r '.objects[]
  | [.id, .name] + (.addresses[] | [.id, .ipValue.ipStr, .hostName])
  | @csv'
```